# Opencv: Get segments sizes in image and remove small segments

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm new to openCV (on Android), can't find what is the way to do basic segmentation on a binary image and get segments (with black pixels) sizes, then delete small segments from image with given threshold. Notice, I don't need to just find contours, I need to get full connected pixels (segment) sizes. After that filter small ones.

The example image is below

[binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMzJM.png)

Comment: what's wrong with findContours there?

Comment: 1. it draws only lines I'm not sure find contours with these parameters  Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE get's all pixels count of segments or not ? 
2. Seems it doesn't give ability to filter small segments, or at least copy segments from one image to other.

Comment: If you can give me an example that would be really helpful

Comment: try function contourArea() after findContours ;)

Comment: I get some values with contourArea, but I'm not sure they are correct or not, because on the image with contours I see many unclosed contours

Comment: you can draw the contours and compare them to your original image. if contours aren't what you are after then you have to show us what exactly you want to achieve. Unfortunately I'm on mobile atm, otherwise I would code the contour stuff for you and upload tons on images with results to discuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with findContours (thanks to @Micka for pushing me).

Here are the code samples for parts which I needed.
1. I did inversion of binary image, because I needed to get black segments
2. Segmentation:

```
    Imgproc.findContours(mat, contours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

3. remove small segments

   each = contours.iterator();
   while (each.hasNext()) {
     MatOfPoint wrapper = each.next();
     double area = Imgproc.contourArea(wrapper);
     if(area <= lengthThreshold){
       each.remove();
     }
   }

4. Draw new image with segments

```
    Imgproc.drawContours(newImg, contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1);
    Imgproc.fillPoly(newImg, contours, new Scalar(0, 0, 0));
```